# Wolfram Alpha API (querying data via Python)

Tags: python, wolframalpha

This is the code:

```
import wolframalpha

app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)

query = 'NFLX Q2 2016 Revenue'
res = client.query(query)

for pod in res.pods:
   print(pod.text)
```

Here's the output:

```
Netflix | revenue | April 2016  to  June 2016
(data not available)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why am I getting "data not available?" What I'm trying to get is the actual number, which is $2.105 billion. Here's the Wolfram link to that: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NFLX+Q2+2016+Revenue.

Maybe the problem is the way the data is presented? I've looked through the API docs but can't seem to find an answer. (Here's a link to the docs by the way: http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation.html).

I just recently started coding, so I'm still a noob. Hopefully someone can help me figure this out. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.